# Check if two pairs of values and keys exist in multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$permissions = array(    
    0 => array(  
        "action"   => "CREATE",  
        "subject"  => "USER"  
    ),  
    1 => array(  
        "action"   => "EDIT",  
        "subject"  => "USER"  
    ),   
    2 => array(  
        "action" =>  "DELETE",  
        "subject" => "USER"  
    ),
    3 => array(  
        "action"   => "CREATE",  
        "subject"  => "TASK"  
    ),  
);
```

I have this code to check if a combination between "key" and "value" there. Works perfectly.

```
    public static function verifyPermissions($array, $key, $val) {
    foreach ($array as $item){
        if ( $item[$key] == $val)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The following line of code returns "TRUE", but there is no combination "action = EDIT" and "subject = TASK" in the same row of the array.

```
if(Group::verifyPermissions($permissions,"action","EDIT") && Group::verifyPermissions($permissions,"subject","TASK"))
```

I need to check these two options simultaneously, in the same row of the array.
How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand your function like this

```
public static function verifyTwoPermissions($array, $keys, $values) {
    foreach ($array as $item){
        if ($item[$keys[0]] == $values[0] && $item[$keys[1]] == $values[1])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// verifyTwoPermissions($permissions, array("action", "subject"), array("EDIT", "TASK"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. works like a charm! i thought of something, but could not finish.